# Как задать папку при загрузке шаблона PHP

Tags: php

Добрый день!
Изучаю PHP на практике, пишу сейчас модуль отвечающий за загрузку шаблонов и столкнулся с небольшой проблемой, надеюсь на вашу помощь.

Шаблон имеет свои теги, например

```
{*HEAD*}
```

на его место загрузится содержимое файла **HEAD.tpl**

```
{:PAGE_TITLE:}
```

на месте этого тега впишется значение переменной соответственно.

при подключении в самом коде шаблона файлов,например CSS, нужно приписывать префикс **{:TEMPLATE:}** в котором прописан путь до папки шаблона

Та же ситуация при включении изображений в коде.

Пример:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{:TEMPLATE:}css/style.css">
<img src="{:TEMPLATE:}images/image.gif">
```

В принципе работает и так, но хотелось бы реализовать автоматическую подстановку пути чтоб при верстке не думать о добавлении псевдотега каждый раз. Вопрос в том, как это можно сделать?

Спасибо

Comment: А что за шаблонизатор, говорите, используется?

Comment: Пишу свой, цель задумки же изучение)

Comment: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/search?q=%D1%81%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B9+%D1%88%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80+is%3Aquestion